# jQuery DataTables using filtered Ember Data - Column widths don't resize

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, datatables

Little background information first:

I have an Ember component that uses a Handlebars `{{#each results as |result|}}{{/each}}` to populate a `tbody` element with a bunch of rows that contain all the data in the results.

Above this table, there is a toggle that sets whether the table should show all the entries or only the ones that have `isEnabled` set to `true`. This toggle sets the `viewAll` component property. When the toggle is flipped, the data changes correctly but the columns in the Datatable extend off the page (as seen below).

I've tried setting and observer on the `viewAll` property so that every time it was changed I called `draw()`. I've tried calling `resultsTable.columns.adjust().draw()`, but to to avail.

Anyone have any idea, what's going on?

For reference the environment uses Bootstrap 3, Ember 2.6.0, Datatables 1.10.12, and jQuery 2.2.4.

Here is the template (the table exists inside a Bootstrap panel-body):

```
<tbody>
    {{#each results as |result|}}
        <!--Ember truth-helpers used here-->
        {{#if (or (and (not viewAll) result.isEnabled) viewAll)}}
            <tr data-id={{result.id}}>
                <td>{{result.time}}</td>
                <td>{{result.a}}</td>
                <td>{{result.b}}</td>
                <td>{{result.c}}</td>
                <td>{{result.d}}</td>
                <td>{{result.e}}</td>
                <td>{{result.f}}</td>
                <td>{{result.g}}</td>
                <td>{{result.h}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Here is the component code (inside the `didInsertElement` hook):

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
    resultsTable = this.$("#tbl_results").DataTable(
        {   
            "responsive":true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "select": true
        }
    );
});
```

And the screenshot:
[Screenshot showing row overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjLbJ.png)

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29

Comment: table{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; // ***********add this
  word-wrap:break-word; // ***********and this
}  ...........................add this css

Comment: Consider implementing it in pure ember. Thats easy and injecting plugins as datatables can get pretty ugly. also you hardly ever need them.

Comment: @Lux, I'm using Datatables for the sorting, searching, pagination, and (most importantly) its responsive view. It wraps cols that don't fit on the screen into expandable child row. The pages that I'm creating need to work across all screen sizes.

Comment: where do you put your `Ember.run.scheduleOnce(...` code?

Comment: Sorry, @ykaragol. That should have been stated earlier. It's inside the `didInsertElement` component hook

Comment: @Curtis a responsive layout can be accomplished without CSS. And the sorting, searching, and pagination is so easy in pure ember!

Comment: Try to use [didRender](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_making-updates-to-the-rendered-dom-with-code-didrender-code) hook (i'm not sure it will be fired though)

Comment: @Lux. I have some custom additions to DataTables that I'd like to keep using, hence the want to stick with it. Also, the responsive extension for DT has this really useful row collapse feature that I'd have to implement myself if I went with Bootstrap responsive table, for example. (See https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive)

Comment: @GennadyDogaev, using `didRender` yields the same results, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Curtis did you try to add some property to your component and observe it's changes? I.e. add property ``redrawTable``, pass yor data to it and redraw table if this prop changes?

Comment: You can also try [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) event (it will be fired when content of element modified), but it will be a bit complicated and not ember-way solution

Comment: @GennadyDogaev - I've tried `draw()`, `responsive.recalc()`, `responsive.rebuild()`, and `columns.adjust()`. The solution for now was to observe the property that holds the results I want in the table, and to destroy and recreate the table any time that property, or the view `isEnabled` property changes. It's definitely not pretty b/c it's a bunch of wasted recreates, but for now, that's what works. I'll look into DOMSubtreeModified, for sure, but I'd like to stick to Ember best practices, because, you know, they're....the....best? :)

Comment: @Curtis yes, solution with observing a property is much better. DOMSubtreeModified can be used in situations when nothing helps, because it will be called a lot of times (i.e. if you add 10 rows, you will get 10 subsequent events, and then if dataTables will do something, you will get those events and it's hard to tell to what event you should react...)

Answer (score 0):

So, as it stands now, with all of the comments ruled out, I've landed at this solution (as stated in one of my comments).

I placed an observer on the `results` set, and the `viewAll` property updated by the toggle:

```
updater : Ember.observer("results.@each", "viewAll", function(){
    recreateTable(this.get("viewAll"), this.get("results"));
}),
```

That calls: (Which destroys the table and recreates it. Terribly inefficient, but the results set us usually decently small, and it's what I'm stuck with for now)

```
function recreateTable(viewAll, results){
    let data = null;
    if(resultsTable) {
        resultsTable.clear(); // Clear first to avoid dupe data
        resultsTable.destroy();
    }
    if (viewAll) {
        data = results;
    } else {
        data = results.filterBy("isEnabled", true);
    }
    let dataArray = [];

    data.forEach( function(item){
        dataArray.push([
                "<time class='timeago' datetime='" + item.get("time") + "'>" + item.get('time') + "</time>",
                item.get("a"),
                item.get("b"),
                item.get("c"),
                item.get("d"),
                item.get("e"),
                item.get("f"),
                item.get("g"),
                item.get("h")
            ]
        );
    });

    resultsTable = Ember.$("#tbl_results").DataTable(
        {   
            "aaData": dataArray,
            "responsive":true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "select": true
        }
    );

    Ember.$("time.timeago").timeago();
}
```

For those curious, timeago is a neat little jQuery plugin that formats times as "3 minutes ago" instead of just lame time stamps. (Even SO uses it). [It can be found here](http://timeago.yarp.com/).

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) (which is great library for date and time manipulation) also can format timestamp as "3 minutes ago". If you'll need to work with dates, I recommend it.